# Parsing number information from an ingredient string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract the quantity information from an ingredient string where the unit has already been removed.

```
175 risotto rice
a little hot vegetable stock (optional)
1     coriander
salt pepper
1 0.5   extra virgin olive oil
1  mild onion
300 split red lentils
1.7   well-flavoured vegetable stock
4  carrots
1 head celery
100 stilton cheese
4   snipped  chives
salt pepper
225 dried flageolet beans
```

These are examples of the strings I am parsing, and the results should look like:

```
175

1

1 0.5
1
300
1.7
4
1
100
4

225
```

My current thinking is using `[0-9]+[ ]*[0-9]*.?[0-9]*` as the regex, however this is picking up the first character after the numerical values, for example 175 risotto rice is returning "175 r"

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not escaping the `.?` into a literal `\.?`. The exact behaviour is still somewhat unclear to me, but using your pattern and escaping the `.` in it should already provide you with the desired matching behavior.

Note that you can shorten `[0-9]` into `\d`:

```
^\d+\s*\d*\.?\d*
```

If you wanted to separately access each number group, you'd need capture groups to correctly deal with that

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you match `.?` which will match an optional character (any character except a newline character) and in your data what will be for example the `r` in risotto or `c` in coriander.

You could use an anchor to assert the start of the string and match 1+ digits followed by an optional part that matches a dot and 1+ digits.

After that match you could add the same optional pattern with a leading 1+ spaces or tabs:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[ \t]+\d+(?:\.\d+))?
```

In Java

```
String regex = "^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:[ \\t]+\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))?";
```

That will match

- `^` Start of the string
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits followed with an optional part `?` that matches a dot and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[ \t]+\d+(?:\.\d+)` match 1+ times a space or tab, 1+ digits and again followed with an optional part that matches a dot and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional

Note that if you want to match the second pattern 0+ times instead of making it optional you could use `*` instead of `?`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/grQGTA/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/CAATYR)